# Conditional Formatting by Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a dataset where I have many columns. I want to highlight everything, click on conditional formatting, and have it color coded by individual columns rather than all the columns. So currently when I highlight everything it color codes every value related to one another but I want to color code numbers in comparison to their respective column.

Is this possible to do in Excel?

Comment: I think you need to add a new rule to each column.  If you have many columns and adding the rules manually seems daunting, you may be able to automate the task with VBA but I don't know what kind of formatting you are looking for so I can't help you too much.

Comment: For those not familiar with VBA/Excel, I recommend you don't attempt to automate relatively small tasks; you will help yourself in the long run by becoming fast at performing small manual tasks. For example - avoid the mouse, and use the ALT + H + ... shortcut mapping to do as much as you possibly can.

Comment: re: *"I want to color code numbers in comparison to their respective column."* What comparison? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to highlight my entire dataset and then color code it based on the values respective columns. I don't want to repeatedly highlight column after column to color code @Jeeped

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible. You just need a new conditional formatting rule for each individual column.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I have a dataset from $A$1:$K$10231. I want to use the Green-Yellow-Red Color Scale

Comment: Click on column A. Go to Conditional Formatting. Click New Rule. "Format All Cells Based on their Values" "3-Colour Scale". Done. Click on column B. Go to Conditional Formatting...